# How to exclude preg_split forward slash followed with string enclosed in single quote

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

**How  to exclude `preg_split` forward slash followed with string enclosed in single quote ?**

I've been struck with this problem quite some.

Below is the code, followed by the output.

```
$str =  "storeid='1,2',categoryname = 'the ultimate \'operating room'";

$match = preg_split("/('[^'\\\\]*')/U", $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($match);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array ( [0] => storeid= [1] => '1,2' [2] => ,categoryname = 'the ultimate \ [3] => 'operating room' [4] => )
```

But here is my Expected Output, I want to exclude \'.

Hope someone understands and helps me out here.

```
Array ( [0] => storeid= [1] => '1,2' [2] => ,categoryname =[3] =>  'the ultimate \'operating room'  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While capturing everything enclosed in single quotes you should pay attention to escpaed single quotes as well. Following this regex:

```
'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'
```

- `'`  A single quote (opening)
- `[^'\\\\]*` All characters except `'` and `\`
- `(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*` Match an escaped character if exists then same previous pattern as much as possible
- `'`  A single quote (closing)

PHP:

```
$match = preg_split("/('[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*')/",
    $str,
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => storeid=
    [1] => '1,\'2'
    [2] => ,categoryname = 
    [3] => 'the ultimate \'operating room'
)
```

Comment: If you do that the pattern will break with any escaped character (between single quotes) that isn't a single quote. You should replace `(?:\\\\'[^'\\\\]*)` with `(?s:\\\\.[^'\\\\\]*)` to handle any escaped characters including newlines.

Comment: I believe that the initial regex I wrote in answer is fine. I'm not sure what I was thinking to while writing descriptions. Thanks anyway. @CasimiretHippolyte